# Visual Studio se detiene en C# con un explorador de archivos creado en mi proyecto

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Lo que pasa es lo siguiente es que yo tengo una aplicación que funciona para hacer un cargue de documentos y enviarlos al servidor, tenía que ver un error y iba a hacer un debugg pero el programa al abrir el explorador de archivos desde mi aplicación se detiene el visual studio de manera local, y no he sabido porque se detiene el visual studio 2019. Quisiera saber si hay una opción en visual que haga que no se detenga mi aplicación y que se siga ejecutando, si no me equivoco esto pasa porque piensa que el explorador de archivos debe terminar el proceso algo que no es así.

Quedo atento a la ayuda.

Comment: Qué dice la pestaña output? Hay alguna excepción? Tienes algún try-catch alrededor del explorador de archivos? Qué has intentado?

Comment: Pues he intentado buscar opciones, en visual studio porque esto ya me había pasado, pero hace mucho tiempo y no recuerdo como lo solucione, porque no solo es este proyecto, son los que sean ejecutados con visual ya sea que esten asociados o no, eso que pasa me detiene por completo

Comment: Y no sale ningún tipo de error solo se detiene, el único de error que me sale es de conexión pero pues por obvias razones de que se detiene el API en C#, se desconecta